# Half wave rectifier input voltage and current waveforms

Tags: power-electronics

ok so i am having a problem in power electronics in my book there is a circuit for a single phase half wave rectifier as shown below and also its related waveforms [image]

and then its performance parameters are discussed and then they show some waveforms which i have also shown here along with the text related to these waveforms[image]

so my questions are:
Q1)why the current waveform is a square wave?
Q2)how can the current (is) can go negative in the second picture i included in my question where as the same current (is) waveform in the first picture(third waveform from the top) is only positive and is a pulse sinusoid instead of a square wave
Q3) referring to the second picture why there is a phase difference between the fundamental component of current and the instantaneous current

Comment: hopefully you people will not let me down and answer my question and clear all of my queries because i have no other option and please forgive me for my bad english

Comment: That current Waveform does not correspond to that schematic.

Comment: Edgar Brown than what is represented by this waveform and in the book this current waveform is presented under the heading of half wave rectifier for reference the book i am reading is power electronics by M H RASHID

Comment: people make mistakes. Textbooks have errors.

Answer (score 1):

As @Edgar Brown stated, the two figures are not related.  In the book, the half-wave rectifier shows the voltage and current waveforms with an ideal diode in the first figure.  The second figure assumes that there is a theoretical input voltage V*s* and a theoretical input current I*s* and is used to demonstrate the calculation of the displacement angle.  Since I*s* is a square wave, the displacement angle is calculated from the fundamental frequency component of I*s* labeled I*s1*.  It is only shown to support the concept of the displacement angle calculation.  I can see that the figure's placement in the text without a clear reference to the displacement angle calculation  could be a little confusing.

Answer (score 0):

Fig. 2 is not meant for resistive load. Consider the converter with inductive load. If the load inductance is less, the input current waveform will be distorted. If the load is highly inductive, the load current will remain almost constant with a small amount of ripple content and the input current will be like a square wave. In addition, there won't be any phase difference between the fundamental component and instantaneous current. Fig. 2 is only to demonstrate the displacement angle between voltage and fundamental current. For more details, refer to "Power Electronics" by Prof. Rashid (4th Edition).